# how to pass data from one view to another view through parentviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have data in read.m class. i created parent view controller for read. so,parent view is home.m.
        in home.m i used present modal view controller for get retailer class. i want data from read.m to retailer.m through the home.m.

```
read.m 

-(void)requestFromtblViews:(id)navigation forIndex:(int)index forText:(NSString *)text withDBdata:(NSArray *)DBdata{
    [DBdata objectAtIndex:index];
}

-(void)showRetailerInfo 
{
    //NSLog(@"show retailer Information is....");
    [self.ReadViewContent  GetshowRetailerInfo:self];
}
```

---

```
home.m

-(void)GetshowRetailerInfo:(id)currentview;
{
    // NSLog(@"get retailer info....");
    Retailer_Info = [[RetailerInfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"RetailerInfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    Retailer_Info.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [Retailer_Info loadDefaultView];
    [self presentViewController:Retailer_Info animated:YES completion:nil];
    [Retailer_Info release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the values or variables global . Declare the variables in `Appdelegate` and then import it where you want to. Also you can Make a singleton Class and import its values . It will be like passing values from one view to the other. As the variables will remain the same but the values will change according to your code.

Please have a look here :-

[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/passing-data-between-view-controllers/

Comment: I DONT WANT CREATE INSTANCE IN APPDELEGATE. HOME IS PARENTCONTROLLER FOR READ. I AM GETTING DATA IN READ.M. HOW TO GET DATA IN HOME?. IF I WILL CREATE INSTANCE FOR HOME IN READ, I AM GETTING ERROR- UNUSED VARIABLE LIKE THIS

Comment: See the obvious way is you will have to create a global variable.... Or import your read.m in your home.m ... create variables in the .h file ....

Comment: read.m  -(void)requestFromtblViews:(id)navigation forIndex:(int)index forText:(NSString *)text withDBdata:(NSArray *)DBdata
{
 [DBdata objectAtIndex:index];  nslog("%@",dBdata)}. AM GETIND DBDATA IN THIS METHOD ONLY. i WANT TO PASS THIS DATA THROUGH                 [(RETAILER *)RETAILER loadViewForArray:[DBdata objectAtIndex:index]];METHOD IN -(VOID)SHOWRETAILERINFO IN READ.M

Comment: DBDATA IS ARRAY. I AM GETTING DATA FROM DATABASE IN THIS METHOD.

Comment: i got data in instance method in read.m. how to pass that data to retailer class. retailer is allocated in home. and implemented present modal view controller

Comment: i am not getting like this

Answer (score 0):

**Use delegate protocol.**

**In Home.h**

```
@protocol RetailerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) passDataToRetailer:(NSArray *)array;

@end

@interface Home:UIViewController
{
 Read readObj;
}
@property(assign, nonatomic) id <RetailerDelegate> delegate;
```

**In Home.m**

```
//call method where you want to pass data
[delegate passDataToRetailer:readObj.array];
```

**In RetailerInfoViewController.h**

```
@interface RetailerInfoViewController : UIViewController<RetailerDelegate>
{
 NSArray *localArray;
}
```

**In RetailerInfoViewController.m**

```
//in viewdidload
Home *parent = [self presentingViewController];
parent.delegate = self;

-(void) passDataToRetailer:(NSArray *)array
{
//here you receive your data
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: CHILD IS READ. READ PARENT IS HOME. THROGH HOME I WANT TO PASS THE DATA IN METHOD TO REATAIL

Comment: i got data in instance method in read.m. how to pass that data to retailer class. retailer is allocated in home. and implemented present modal view controller

Comment: @Ram So you want read class object which is present as instance in home, pass data to Retailer(presented modally on home). Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to acess the properties of another class first you need to import that .h file where you want and make object of that class. and access which method...

Suppose you need to acess the second view controller properties into FirstViewController.Then define SecondViewController.h file into FirstViewController.and make object

```
SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:Nil];

controller.method;
```

// method what you want to access here...

Comment: i got data in instance method in read.m. how to pass that data to retailer class. retailer is allocated in home. and implemented present modal view controller

Comment: you need to create objcet of that class and aceess using that object  like object.property...

Comment: in read if i will create object to home, am getting error. unused variable

Comment: If you want to create any other class objcet into next class ffirst need to declare that class in .h #import ""  Like this and then create objcet and then        SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:Nil];

controller.method;